# log4net adonetappender variable is null

Tags: variables, stored-procedures, logging, log4net, adonetappender

After googling this for what seems like forever, I have resorted to asking the question here.

I have added a custom field and variable to the log4net adonetappender. However, after re-working it and trying all practically every suggestion found in the first 4 pages of google, the variable still comes out null.

Any ideas why this happening and any suggestions to help?

Output

```
RowId   Username    DateOfActivity  Thread  Level   Logger  Message Exception
16  (null)  2015-08-27 18:53:40.607 124732  DEBUG   LogToDatabaseTest.Form1 Retrieving info for ID
```

App.Config

```
<parameter>
<parameterName value="@username"/>
<dbType value="String" />
<size value="100" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{username}"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date"/>
    <dbType value="DateTime"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@thread"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="255"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%thread"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_level"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="50"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@logger"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="255"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="4000"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@exception"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="4000"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout"/>
  </parameter>
```

C# code to set the variable

```
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ThreadContext.Properties["username"] = SystemInformation.UserName;

log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();//(Watch = false)


try
{
    long_ID = Int64.Parse(textEdit1.Text);
}

catch (FormatException fe)
{
    XtraMessageBox.Show("ID inputted is not a number! Please enter a valid ID", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);

    log.Error(String.Format("Retrieving Info for ID: {0}", textEdit1.Text), fe);

    return;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above was working, it was an error in my programming logic. The variable was not set when the logged events were hit.